# How is it possible for the RPA bot to look constantly in a folder if there is a new File?

Tags: robotics, blueprism, rpa

This file is stored in "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer". It should be added to the queue.

It is not sure when the file is added, because it is created by an other application, that has nothing to do with rpa.

Comment: "*How is it possible*...?" It's possible because Blue Prism has the capability. Not exactly sure what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: I mean, how this works. How can I tell blueprism: "please look constantly if there is a new file. If there is a new file, conduct process XY".

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have action "Utility - File Management: File exist?", and you have action "Utility - General:Sleep". If you combine these two, then you'll have the answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Unlike some other RPA platforms/automation solutions, Blue Prism doesn't have a native capability to "watch" a folder and trigger process executions outside of having a resource constantly polling for the file you'd like to watch for in an infinite loop.